# React/Redux Search Bar not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, searchbar

I have a search bar on my TODO List:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FilterTasks } from '../../redux/actions/searchbar';
import reducers from '../../redux/reducers';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class SearchBar extends Component {
    render() {
      const {search, value} = this.props;

      return (
          <input
            className="form-control"
            placeholder = "Filter Tasks"
            onChange={(e) => FilterTasks(e.target.value)}
            value={value} />
      );
    }
  } 

  function mapStateToProps({tasks}) {
    return {value: tasks.value};
  }

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({FilterTasks}, dispatch);
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

Here's my action to filter:

```
export const SEARCH = 'SEARCH';

export function FilterTasks(value) {
  return {type: SEARCH, value};
}
```

My search bar reducer:

```
import {SEARCH} from '../actions/searchbar';

const initialState = {}

export default function SEARCHREDUCER(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SEARCH: {
      const {value} = action;
      const tasks = state.contents.filter((val) => val.includes(value));
      return {...state, value, tasks};
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

My Index reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import SEARCHREDUCER from '../reducers/searchbar';

const TaskReducer = (state = [] ,action) => {
    switch (action.type){
    case 'ADD_TASK':
    state = state.concat(action.payload);
    break;
    case 'DELETE_TASK':
  state = state.tasks.filter(task => task !== action.payload)
    break;
    }
    return state;
},

reducers = combineReducers({
    tasks : TaskReducer,
    SEARCHREDUCER 
});

export default reducers;
```

And my TasksList class where the filtered list should be rendered:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Task from '../task'

class TaskList extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Tasks</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.tasks.map((task,index) => <Task key={index} task={task} />)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}

function MapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        tasks:state.tasks,
    }
}

export default connect (MapStateToProps)(TaskList);
```

My problem here is that when I type an entry on the search bar the Tasks list does not change at all, It's not showing any kind of error. What i'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FilterTasks(e.target.value)` should be `this.props.FilterTasks(e.target.value)` instead, otherwise it'll call the the imported function from actions that is not bound to Redux by your `mapDispatchToProps`.

Also, your `TaskReducer` and `SEARCHREDUCER` are wrong. The `reducer` variable is the one with the combined state, not `TaskReducer` or `SEARCHREDUCER`.

You should just keep the search string in state and do the filtering within `TaskList` with `this.props.tasks.filter(<insert filter function>).map(<insert map function>)`.

Comment: I changed it and now i'm getting error: searchbar.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at SEARCHREDUCER

Comment: You completely misunderstood `combineReducers`. Read more examples on what it does. `reducer` variable is the one with the combined state, not `TaskReducer` or `SEARCHREDUCER`. See my edit.